# Will the healthcare premiums of a 64 year old making $26,500 a year grow to $14,600 under the GOP Health Care Plan?

Tags: united-states, politics, healthcare

This picture was posted on the Facebook page, [The Other 98%](https://www.facebook.com/TheOther98/).

> [image: A 64 year old making $26,500 a year would pay a premium of $1,700 Obamacare $14600 Republicare When Paul Ryan calls this "an act of mercy" he must mean a mercy killing]

Is this really true? Will the premium be more than half of the income of a 64 year old under the proposed new system? And is the old rate true?

Answer (score 141):

This figure has been extracted from the Congressional Budget Office (CBO) report.

[Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2017/03/14/this-may-be-the-most-brutal-number-in-the-cbo-report/?utm_term=.f8afa403af27):

> According to the CBO, 64-year olds making $26,500 per year would see their premiums increase by an estimated 750 percent by 2026. While they are on track to pay $1,700 under the current law, the CBO projects the American Health Care Act would force them to pay $14,600. Even if you grant that inflation will allow them to make slightly more money by 2026, that's still about half of their income going to health care.

They point to a table from the CBO report:

[image: High Resolution Chart of Insurance Costs]

Like all economic modelling, the CBO report is based on assumptions that you might disagree with, but the original claim is not invented - it is backed by a reasonable source.

The parameters used in this example do seem to be chosen to illustrate a very hard-hit demographic, so while they are real and might in fact be illustrative, they don't represent all Americans:

- The chart as a whole is for *non-group* health insurance plans offered to individuals. [At the time of the 2016 census (PDF)](https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/library/publications/2016/demo/p60-257.pdf), 56% of the US population was covered by *employee-based group plans*, while only 16% were covered by the kind of non-group direct-purchased plan discussed here (but that is still over 52 million Americans).
- Premiums increase with the age of the covered individual, but since someone *65 or older* may be eligible for Medicare, age 64 represents the age with maximum premiums.
- The "premium tax credit" is calculated based on income, so individuals earning significantly *less* than $26,500 a year would be eligible for higher credits, or might qualify for Medicaid (depending on state participation).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55451/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-will-the-healthcare-premiums-of-a-64-year-ol).

Comment: Here's a link to the CBO report: [CBO Cost Estimate - American Health Care Act](https://www.cbo.gov/sites/default/files/115th-congress-2017-2018/costestimate/americanhealthcareact.pdf). The quoted "Table 4 - Illustrative Example" table is on page 35.